# Menu system tutorial

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Dear code-benders. 
I am trying to do a menu-system in core JSF 2.0 for a simple web-application. I do have different user with different roles (admin, user, guest, etc.), which I load with JPA from a database. So i will try to create a dynamic meny-system and stick it in a left aligned panel. I've searched the web for something like this, but for the most of time I find examples in RichFaces, PrimeFaces and others not core jsf.

Can anyone be kind to point me in a direction where I can get the fundamentals (tutorial/example) ideas to build a menu-system in core JSF 2.0 ?

Greetings Chris

PS. Consider to use RichFaces, but I want see if it's easy with core jsf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A menu is just a bunch of links which usually go in a HTML `<ul><li>`. You can use CSS to give it a nice look'n'feel, but that's not immediately the responsibility of JSF.

If it's a flat list, just do

```
<ul>
    <ui:repeat value="#{menu.list}" var="item">
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{item.accepts(user.roles)}">
            <li><a href="#{item.url}">#{item.name}</a></li>
        </ui:fragment>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

If it's a tree, then you really need to head to a 3rd party component library since the standard JSF component library does not contain a component which supports iteratin/displaying a tree structure. Lot of 3rd party component libraries have kind of a `<xx:tree>` component.

You can also create a custom tree iterator component yourself which doesn't render any markup. Here's a kickoff example of how the view side can look like:

```
<xx:tree value="#{menu.tree}" var="item">
    <xx:treeNode level="0">
        <xx:treeNodeItem rendered="#{item.accepts(user.roles)}">
            <h3>#{item.name}</h3>
            <xx:insertTreeNodeChildren />
        </xx:treeNodeItem>
    </xx:treeNode>
    <xx:treeNode>
        <ul>
            <xx:treeNodeItem rendered="#{item.accepts(user.roles)}">
                <li>
                    <a href="#{item.url}">#{item.name}</a>
                    <xx:insertTreeNodeChildren />
                </li>
            </xx:treeNodeItem>
        </ul>
    </xx:treeNode>
</xx:tree>
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late replay. So I guess I have to decide if need nested menus (tree) or not. And if I need to implement a collapsible left menu panel. Which I can do with JS and icons in core JSF, I guess. It's a bit strange that the core JSF 2.0 don't have a tree view component, for easy menu building. Thanks for the pattern suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you don get enough satisfaction from JSF2 components, maybe you should implement a 3rd party component, it doesn't mean that you have to couple your solution whit this components, maybe you could try an extra layer to plug in any component in your JSF UI. By another hand, latest versions of primefaces and icefaces has native implementation whit JSF2 and you don't have to worry about developing extra things to plug in their components. You could have a menu tree whit primefaces, and the rest of your pages in pure JSF2. Only you need are managed beans and other classic components of JSF2 API. By the way, this could be implemeted too whit facelets that comes natively whit JSF2.

I hope this comment help's you.

Regards.